# grouping regex help

Tags: c#, regex

I have this regex for defining identifiers:

```
[\w|@|#|_][\w|\.|\$|@|#|_]*
```

I need to allow as well groups of identifier that are grouped using [group] or "group" and for allowing "s inside the "group" you would need to write "" (two) and the same for the [group] you would do ]] for one ].

the group might contain anything allowed in identifiers, spaces and any of these characters:
tilde (~)
hyphen (-)
exclamation point (!)
left brace ({)
percent (%)
right brace (})
caret (^)
apostrophe (')
ampersand (&)
period (.)
left parenthesis (()
backslash ()
right parenthesis ())
accent grave (`)

Examples :

```
"asda$@.asd ' a12876 ]] "" " => asda$@.asd ' a12876 ]] " 

[asda$@.asd ' a12876 ]] "" ] => asda$@.asd ' a12876 ] ""
```

Comment: Have you considered the possibility of parsing this in another way than using regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need any of the `|` in your `[character classes]` because it causes any character to match.  (I am assuming you don't want identifiers to begin with `|`, for example.

```
string mystring = "[asda$@.asd ' a12876 ]] \"\" ]";
Console.WriteLine(mystring);
MatchCollection matches = 
   Regex.Matches(mystring,
                 @"[\w@#](?:[\w\.\$@#])*|\[[\w@#](?:\[\[|\]\]|[""\w\s\.\$@#'])*\]|""[\w@#](?:\""\""|['\s\[\w\.\$@#\]])*""",
                 RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);
foreach (Match match in matches)
{
   string id = match.Value;
   // The first character of the match tells us which escape sequence to use
   // for the replacement.
   if (match.Value[0] == '[')
      id = id.Substring (1, id.Length - 2).Replace ("[[", "[").Replace ("]]", "]");
   else if (match.Value[0] == '"')
      id = id.Substring (1, id.Length - 2).Replace ("\"\"", "\"");
   Console.WriteLine (id);
}
```

Comment: it should replace the ]] with ] as well. just like when it is a "group" it should replace a "" with a "

Comment: The passive subexpressions are missing the underscore (_)

Comment: @Doug D.  I may not be seeing what you are seeing.  `\w` includes `_`.  I guess I forgot to remove that from the character class.  Will fix.

Comment: @luis, I'm not sure I understood your request.  I added some replacement stuff.  Take a look when you get a chance.

Comment: @agent-j, you're correct. '\w' includes '_'. My mistake. I was simply comparing the characters and noticed the difference.